# Spring Boot rest API encoding error

Tags: java, jquery, spring, post, spring-boot

I create a small service which take a string from UI textarea, and pass the string to a spring boot rest service, the string include a piece of java code and will be analyzed by spring logic and push the result back into UI again, here I have the string problem

In UI project, the code is:

```
var sendCode = function(){
      var code = $(".textarea").val();
      console.log(code);
      var url = "http://localhost:8080/simpleoj";
      var success = function(data){
        $("#finalResult").html(data);
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: code,
        success: success
      });
    }
```

where the url is the destination the post should go

In the back end, I have the code as follows:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;

@RestController
public class WebController{

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/simpleoj",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = {})
    public String greetings(@RequestBody String bodyContent) throws Exception{

        String source =  bodyContent;
        System.out.println(source);
        //I have remove the logic, because it is not important
        }
    }
}
```

when I deploy all of these, I found the logic can not execute because the bodyContent shows as below:

```
public+class+Solution%7Bpublic+int+add%28%29%7Breturn+1+1%3B%7D%7D=
```

which is not what I want!

I want it to be as follows:

```
public class Solution{public int add{return 1+1;}}
```

when I test in POSTman, it is working fine.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: By the way, it is typical, though certainly not necessary, to use form encoding rather than a request body for form POSTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the param is econded as URL. You can use in order to decode

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(bodyContent, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: but the problem is when I code as you suggested, I have another issue, the problem is the return statement is 1+1, so when encode it the '+' will be dismissed. To be honest, I just want to get a pure string from textarea, and when I integrate them together, the string I get is missing a '+' and add a '=' at the end.

Comment: This is because the String is not well encoded, it shoud be public+class+Solution%7Bpublic+int+add%7Breturn+1%2B1%3B%7D%7D

Comment: I found the way to solve it, first in the post in jQuery, I should add the follows: contentType: "plain/text; charset=utf-8", dataType: "text", and in the RestController, I add the headers={Accept=text}, I don't whether it matters, but my problem solved, thanks for all guys helping me.

Comment: But the only thing I am concerning is, why it is encoded as URL, I mean why?

Comment: I don't understand why spring is giving you the encoded value. I think, it could be because of your controller configuration.